# Airflow: Subdag Fails Without Scheduling Tasks or Generating Log

Tags: airflow

I'm running into a situation with the airflow instance (version 1.8) I manage where I am seeing tasks which are Subdags fail, but the log for the failed task is either `*** Task instance did not exist in the DB` or no log at all. The tasks run daily, and only fail intermittently. The Subdag works most of the time, but fails occasionally and without explanation.

When I read through the logs from around the time of the failure, I'm seeing two things:

1. No log explanation of why the Subdag failed
   a. The database shows that the task has a `End Date`, but not a `Start Date`
2. None of the tasks in the Subdag got scheduled

I've dug through the documentation, pulled the logs from the whole server, and upgraded the size (CPU, memory, and disk) of the server hosting the airflow logs. I'm guessing it has to do with a timeout, but can't seem to find where the issue is originating.

---

More details (one instance):

- `Queued Dttm`: 3:38:04
- `Start Date`: NULL
- `End Date`: 03:38:25
- `Duration`: NULL
- `Try Number`: 1 (no retries used)

---

Possible theory - fails when there are task scheduling deadlocks. Currently, the instances where it fails are ones where there are lots of equally prioritized parallel tasks. It's not giving that error message, but lacking other options I'm trying to identify patterns.

---

This appears to be related to issue [#1473](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW/issues/AIRFLOW-1473). If they're not the same, the symptoms are the same.